# Why does Youtube Analytics Api groups.list method only returns at most 20 groups?

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-analytics, youtube-analytics-api

My first post on stackoverflow :)

I have been trying to use the  YouTube Analytics API to list all analytics groups of a content owner. I tried both

1. via APIs-Explorer web: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtubeAnalytics/v1/youtubeAnalytics.groups.list
2. via python: youtube_analytics.groups().list(onBehalfOfContentOwner=Content_Owner_Name).execute()

Both only returned at most 20 groups (the actual total number of groups are in hundreds). Wondering if anyone knows the cause of this issue, or any additional argument to specify/increase the maximum number of results

Many thanks in advance!

Here's a brief description of what's returned in python:

```
{"etag": "A String", 
 "items": [{"contentDetails": {"itemCount": "A String",
                               "itemType": "A String",
                              },
             "etag": "A String",
             "id": "A String",
             "kind": "youtube#group",
             "snippet": {"publishedAt": "A String",
                         "title": "A String",
                        },
           },
           {"contentDetails": {"itemCount": "A String",
                               "itemType": "A String",
                              },
             "etag": "A String",
             "id": "A String",
             "kind": "youtube#group",
             "snippet": {"publishedAt": "A String",
                         "title": "A String",
                        },
           },
           {"contentDetails": {"itemCount": "A String",
                               "itemType": "A String",
                              },
             "etag": "A String",
             "id": "A String",
             "kind": "youtube#group",
             "snippet": {"publishedAt": "A String",
                         "title": "A String",
                        },
           },
           # ...  20 items in such format
          ],
 "kind": "youtube#groupListResponse"
}
```

I don't see any thing indicating a total item count, or link to a "next page"

Comment: Can you share what's returned? 
I'm thinking the API returns pages of 20 items, but then the result should include the total item count or a 'next page' link or something.

Comment: I included a brief description of the returned object in the original post.

Comment: Can you include some of the actual values of the results (item count, type, id, etc)? Just having "A String" isn't very useful. What's the exact number of groups you're expecting to get? Also note that "an Analytics group can only contain resources that you have uploaded or claimed or that are linked to a channel that you administer. As a result, channel owners can create groups of videos and playlists. Content owners can create groups of videos, playlists, channels, or assets" ([source](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/groups#Groups)).